# How can I calculate the number of attempts required to gain enough tokens for a prize?

Tags: probability

## Problem

A carnival has rolled into town. One of the stalls is offering a grand prize in exchange for **47 tickets**, which you obtain from a machine. The machine is played by inserting 50¢ and pulling a lever. The machine will then randomly print out **1-5 tickets**. The machine will always print at least 1 ticket.

The probabilities of receiving any given number of tickets are:

| Number of tickets printed | Probability per play |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10% |
| 2 | 20% |
| 3 | 50% |
| 4 | 15% |
| 5 | 5% |

How do you calculate the minimum and maximum number of plays you would need to make in order to gain enough tickets for the grand prize?

### Own research

I've looked at formulas for loot boxes and [gatcha boxes](https://dskjal.com/statistics/how-to-calculate-chance.html) but the problems and solutions are presented as either the probability of receiving a particular item in *X* attempts or the minimum number of attempts required to gain at least one of each desired item.

Comment: Patricio answered : "How do you calculate the minimum and maximum number of plays you would need...".  However, is this the question that you really wish to pose?  That is, are you sure that you wish to ask a question that is not in any way associated with Probability theory?

Comment: See comment left to you following the answer of Patricio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best case scenario is that you always get $5$ tickets. In that case you need to insert $50$ cents $10$ times. The worst case is that you get $1$ ticket every time you play, in which case you need $47$ plays.

Comment: @Talon: When you look at "minimal/maximal number of steps" problems, probability rarely plays a role, because a series of steps (as long as each step of it is possible) can be a minimal/maximal solution to the problem, no matter the low probability for all of them to occur. That's what Patricio correctly described. Since the problem sounds like it comes from a textbook, and those usually don't try to "trick" the reader, there is a chance that you misunderstood the final question and it asks about some expected number of plays, or similar. Just reread it to make sure you got that right.

Comment: @Ingix Talon is not *registered* to this answer.  I filled the gap by leaving Talon a comment, following the question, which directs Talon to your comment.  For info on *comment addressing*, see [this article](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thank you, @Patricio, for your answer. It was fairly obvious now that you pointed it out. What I really wanted to know, and failed to frame properly in the question, was what is the likelihood of gaining enough enough tickets in fewer than 10 attempts.

Comment: Thank you, @Ingix, for explaining the problem with the question and why it doesn't fit with the probability subject. It is a real world problem that I simplified. It was natural for me to see the chances of getting a given number of tickets per play and assume it was a probability problem. As mentioned in my comment to Patricio, I don't think I understood the right way to frame the problem.

Comment: @Talon. That's a different question. From my answer, you see that it's impossible to gain enough tickets in *fewer* than $10$ attemps, because $10$ is the minimum and, hence, $9$ is impossible.